# Minimal $\Bbb F_q[x,y]$ polynomial with some local properties.

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

What is the least degree polynomial in $\Bbb F_q[x,y]$ that vanishes only at $(0,0)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,1)$ and $(4,3)$ where prime $q$ may be different from prime $5$? What happens $\Bbb F_q$ is replaced by $\Bbb R$?

Comment: By degree, you mean total degree, right?

Comment: I think such a polynomial has to have some kind of symmetry in $x,y$ variables.

Comment: And this least degree that you seek. Do you expect that it will be a constant, independent of $q$? Or do you expect it to be expressed in terms of $q$?

Comment: @quasi I think it will be constant.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?